How can I customize the display of exchange/finance figures in Notification Center on macOS?
On my old 10.10.5 Yosemite Mac, I had a nice display of Exchange figures like
this in the Notification Center like this :

On my 13.0 Ventura Mac the display is different :

I find the old display much better than the new one (in the old display you see all the main figures immediately, while in the new display you see no figures at all and the list is much shorter)
Can the new widget be configured to get the old display back ?

When editing your widgets you have Stocks widgets that are very similar to the previous display (showing 6 stocks). You can click the "Edit Widgets..." button and then choose between these.


